# Take value from each line of a file and search for it in another file in Unix?

Tags: unix, terminal

I have two files. I want my Unix code to take each first column from each line of File A as a variable and look for it in File B. If found, I want the found line in File B to be saved in an output file.

```
File A:
1335 skrgrsjgls 1231
12213 23rerwsdf 9605
11567 4693460 0340592
54321 293402460 324

File B: 
-54321 Apples
-23453 Grapes
-1335 Pears
-65363 Pineapples
-96506 Grapefruit

Expected Output File:
-1335 Pears
-54321 Apples
```

Code I have tried:

```
    for i in $(cat File A); do grep -w $i File B > FileC; done
```

I get no result for this. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: your given command should also work just put the `>>` before FileC

Comment: When the filenames `File A` and `File B` really have a space, use quotes around the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it works for you. This could be done with `grep` command which is used to search patterns in the file.

```
for i in $(cat FileA.txt); do   grep -i "$i" FileB.txt >> output.txt; done
```

### OUTPUT

```
HaLF-MenTaL@DESKTOP-7B47GH0 MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ for i in $(cat FileA.txt); do   grep -i "$i" FileB.txt >> output.txt; done

HaLF-MenTaL@DESKTOP-7B47GH0 MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ cat output.txt
-1335 Pears
-54321 Apples
```

this one is the output for yours tested command.

```
HaLF-MenTaL@DESKTOP-7B47GH0 MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ for i in $(cat FileA.txt); do grep -i "$i" FileB.txt | head -10; done
-1335 Pears
-54321 Apples
```

Comment: The "$(cat FileA.txt)" part doesn't register any reads and I don't understand why.

Comment: @user20330606 does your output file iempty? do you try the one which i mentioned in your question's comment.

Comment: to test it out, I've done 

for i in $(cat FileA.txt); do   grep -i "$i" FileB.txt | head -10; done

but it doesn't give any results.

Comment: I think its because I have a "\n" at the end of each line. How would I discard that?

Comment: @user20330606 i had added the outputs. i had tested these command in git bash cuz i am not using linux. everything is working fine for me.

Comment: Your solution also looks for values in the third column like `1231`.  You might want to use `cut -d '  '  -f1 FileA.txt `.

Comment: How would the order go for that ```for i in $(cat FileA.txt); do grep -i "$i" FileB.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 FileA.txt >> FileC; done``` ??? @WalterA

Comment: `for i in $(cut -d '  '  -f1 FileA.txt); do   grep -i "$i" FileB.txt >> output.txt; done`

Answer (score 1):

For large files you should avoid loops with a new `grep` for each line.
`awk` is a great tool, an other solution is

```
grep -f <(sed -r 's/([^ ]*).*/^-\1 /' FileA) FileB
```

The part `<(sed -r 's/([^ ]*).*/^-\1 /' FileA)` is creating a kind of in-memory file of strings you want to look for (start of line with `^`, hyphen, number, space),
and `grep -f file` uses the "file" as multiple strings to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the following solved my problem. I thank everyone who contributed to the question and I am sure their version also works.

```
    while read -r line; do var=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}') grep -w "$var" FileB > FileC; done < FileA
```

Comment: With a line like `1335 * 1231` the `*` will be expanded, "always" use quotes with strings and replace `echo $line` with `echo "$line"`.

Comment: `awk` is a tool that loops through a file. The combination `do ... done` and `awk` is most of the times "wrong", especially when you also use `grep` in the loop. Consider the answer of @Franck.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that loops should be avoided for large files and that `awk` is a good alternative. Try doing:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$0; next } $1 in a { print a[$1] }' FileB.txt FileA.txt > Output.txt
```

The `FNR==NR` part ensure that the next block is only executed for the first file,
`{ a[$1]=$0; next }` will save the first col of FileB.txt as an array,
`$1 in a` will check if that key exists in FileA.txt,
`{ print a[$1] }` prints the matches that are found,
`FileB.txt FileA.txt` are the arguments given to the cmd line (careful with the order),
and `> Output.txt` saves that print to an output file.